# Simple Jackson Array string addition

Tags: jackson, gson

I am trying to convert GSON to jackson I have a method that returns a gson JsonObject.  However it only creates a JsonArray,  and returns that so I assume there is a simple casting there.  So what would be the Jackson Equivalent?  Now the method only adds one string at a time. So I need something like this:

```
 JsonNode node = new JsonNode();
 node.add("String 1");
 node.add("String 2');
```

but would come out like this:

```
["String 1","String 2"]
```

I could create a List  and map it from there, but I want to do this raw.

This seems too simple as google has given me many suggestions that are far beyond what this simple exercise requires.

And if anyone has a nice blog to tutorial on how to convert Gson to Jackson that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is a bit tricky - you create an array node through JsonNode factory method:

```
ArrayNode arrNode = (ArrayNode)new JsonNode().withArray("my_array");  // arg is arrray propertry name
arrNode.add("String 1");
arrNode.add("String 2');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to create `ArrayNode`, `ObjectMapper` has method `createArrayNode()`, along with `createObjectNode()`. You can then add entries to it, as well as add node itself into other arrays, or as property in `ObjectNode`.

Actual construction of nodes by mapper is done using configurable `JsonNodeFactory`; default implementation of which simple constructs one of standard implementation types like `ObjectNode` and `ArrayNode`.